# Problem with cookies in beautifulsoup loop

Tags: python, loops, cookies, beautifulsoup

I collect several information on a site, societe.com. For a few pages it works fine. Here is part of my shortened code

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urlsbourgogne = [
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AGILIS-COMPTABILITE-902252782.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ALD-VOLAILLES-877535864.html",
]

headers = {
    "User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36"
}

data = []
for url in urlsbourgogne:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser"
    )
    title = soup.select_one("#identite_deno").get_text(strip=True)
    try:
        jugement = list(soup.select_one('td.red').stripped_strings)[0].split('le ')[0]
    except:
        print("Je n'ai pas trouvé de type de jugement pour " + title)
        jugement = "En activité"

    try:
        typeact = form = soup.select_one("#ape-histo-description").get_text(strip=True).split(" (")[0]
    except:
        print("Je n'ai pas trouvé de type d'activité pour " + title)
        typeact = "None"

data.append([title, url , jugement, typeact])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=["Title",  "URL" ,"Active" "Type d'activité"],
)
```

But my problem is when I launch this loop with a large number of urls the site "blocks" me and displays fictitious pages with false information. For example here are some of the urls I would like to use (sorry it's a bit long)

```
urlsbourgogne = [
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AGILIS-COMPTABILITE-902252782.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ALD-VOLAILLES-877535864.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ALLIANCE-ESCALIER-791602170.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ARCHIPLAN-878552645.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/B-TAM-(BETON-TECHNIQUES-AMELIORATIONS-528367741.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/B.V.M.-337641898.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/B2M-508740941.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BIDEAU-SECTEUR-SANTE-538094814.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BIOAUTOCENTER-838121424.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BMN-OPTIC-893675140.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/CG-MULTI-COM-813187788.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/CHALON-CONSEIL-EXPERTISE-BOURGOGNE-478873078.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/CHATEAU-ELEGANCE-534269956.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/D.L.H.-481789147.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/DC-COMPANY-831435037.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/DEVECI-803963354.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ESPACE-ANIMAL-849236443.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/EURL-CPS-71-498295583.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/FAINDT-CONSEIL-DEVELOPPEMENT-753631365.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/FRANCE-CUST'HOME-840435176.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/FRANCE-RENOVATION-ET-CONSTRUCTION-882213440.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/INDUSTRIE-BOURGUIGNONNE-DE-LA-CONSTRU-850780875.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/INTERPAIN-822877551.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/JBK-MULTI-SERVICES-808106132.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/JFG-CONDUITE-539108647.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LA-CADOLE-837853548.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LA-TROPICALE-808438295.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LE-CLOS-DES-TOURELLES-489163691.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LES-NECTARS-DE-MARINE-888982972.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LES-PIASTRES-420307175.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LES-TENDANCES-D'ALODIS-901642652.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LHS-ELECTRO-AMEUBLEMENT-384367835.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LT-COM-804735215.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LYON-BOURGOGNE-VTC-844296848.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/M.A.D.I.D.---MONTAGE-ASSISTANCE-DEPAN-808481550.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MELIEWASH-887637866.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MSV-751338443.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/N.R.J.-HABITAT-414387381.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/NIVERNAISE-DE-TRAVAUX-PUBLICS-PHILIPPEAU-950376582.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/PALAIS-D'AGADIR-753994086.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/PERFORMANCE-ET-TRADITION-490041175.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/POTERIE-NORMAND-SN-830796827.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/PRH-21-817394265.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/PRO-FILTRATION71-822592572.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/R-SERVICES-852189679.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/REFERENCE-COIFFURE-391911831.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SAM'EVEIL-852758945.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SARL-DAUVERGNE-414090811.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SARL-ECS-890074180.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SARL-MENUISERIE-BOYER-432882934.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SAS-7'IDEAL-844229609.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/STBS-821854619.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/STOC-ASSAINISSEMENT-341938710.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/T.F.B-801699182.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/TPC-TRANSPORT-EXPRESS-494102106.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/TRUST-BARBER-SHOP-877618199.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/VERANDA-DES-AMOGNES-848424537.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/VERNIAU-VINCENT-812261618.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/A3XX-445387475.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AFFINAGE-D'ALUMINIUM-PREMERY-809693658.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AJC-DISTRIBUTION-449093095.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AMIRO-843832080.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ANALYSE-DIAG-EXPERT-BATIMENT-849818422.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AR'ELEC-498992270.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ASSYSTRONIC-528707680.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ATELIER-AMB-838572253.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ATOL-LES-OPTICIENS-LIMOGES-538695610.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AU-NEUVY-SOIS-850222019.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AUX-DOUCEURS-D'ETANG-837596766.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AUX-RICOCHETS-877773796.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BADRI-&-CONSTRUCTION-853737864.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BEAUNE-COLLECTOR-752092361.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BOURGOGNE-ENERGIE-CHAUFFAGE-CLIMATISA-808185623.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BOUZID-794032078.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BUROPA-SARL-378436257.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/CAPUCINES-CO-834616302.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/CHOUETTE-BUSINESS-853161768.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/CMC-BOURGOGNE-488344474.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/COCO-CREATION-888524105.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/CONCEPT-BATI-DECO-PLAISANCE-517499778.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/CONCEPT-BAUMGARTEN-841374580.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/CUMA-ASTER-304850845.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/DAVID-BERNARD-530946656.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/DIJON-RELAIS-CARTE-GRISE-842384018.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/DS-AUTO-VO-825296114.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ECO-CONSTRUCTION-503496176.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/EDDY-SAHRAOUI-840429807.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ELLYPSE-889445193.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ESPACE-PARE-BRISE-GLASS-501232813.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/EURL-BICLOUNE-PIQUET-887651123.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/EURL-PLYMS-841084023.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/FIRE-PROTECT-524120870.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/FORM-VITALE-433558186.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/FRANCK-ESPACES-VERTS-ET-MULTISERVICES-448837476.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/GALERIE-PREVOTEAU-DU-CLARY-902974963.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/GLS-ELECTRICITE-510933690.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/GROUPE-ARTISANAL-DU-BATIMENT-821969805.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/HELLO-WORLD-824882427.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/HIGHEREDME-814311247.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/HOPALE-845025121.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/J2MV-518942123.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/JULEX-898377254.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/KOSTECKI-LANNY-798413340.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/L'ATELIER-GOURMAND-841829898.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/L'ATELIER-MEDICAL-850846510.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/L'EPISODE-853446144.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LA-BICYCLETTE-DE-PAUL-844989574.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LA-BOUTIQUE-DES-SERVICES-752545665.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LA-MAISON-DE-LA-PIZZA-818225807.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LA-MESURE-DES-POSSIBLES-893185454.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LA-PEINTURE-FRANCAISE-822949194.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LA-VIEILLE-TOUR-804460384.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LE-STUDIO-819886979.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LES-PETITS-COLIBRIS-840001085.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LOIRE-MEDICAL-SANTE-499285757.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/M-B-CONSEIL-448431429.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MACON-EVENT-840834881.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MH-CLEAN-CONFLUENCE-899227359.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MON-KOCHON-891295545.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/NEW-INFORMATIQUE-SYSTEM-SERVICES-839506011.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/O.T.O.P-849205950.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ODABAS-792577033.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/OXYGENE-LA-DECO-QUI-RESPIRE-887884278.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/PALLE-DAMIEN-481522175.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/PECHIODAT-331169672.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/PIERRE-PAULIN-504978081.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/PRO-SANITAIRE-531154441.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/PROFESSIONNELS-L-ENTRETIEN-AUTOMOBILES-437668635.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/PYRAMIDE-450734595.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SARL-LE-DANI-GOURMAND-520564691.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SAS-ANDRE-BARBOSA-890709231.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SAS-BRASSERIE-DU-GRAND-BOIS-899806780.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SAS-MOREL-753954627.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SAS-NF-CONSTRUCTION-853882967.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SAVEUR-DE-ROME-832030308.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SELARL-RUELLE-WEBER-GAMBIER-534922828.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SENS-515015659.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SYSTEME-V-818436453.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/TAOSO-822806659.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/TRD-823286968.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/VERT-ET-CO-809242506.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/VINCENT-DEBUT-887831766.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/VOTRE-QUOTIDIEN-FACILE-841654445.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ADOMIE-849316740.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ALEX-CONSTRUCTION-&-RENOVATION-831234893.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/APH-794633693.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ARBO-STYL-504103615.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AU-BON-ENDROIT-898543616.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AU-P'TIT-MORVAN-803080506.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BATIMENT-CONSTRUCTION-RENOVATION-SARL-891807596.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BLACK-LION-879760916.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BOUCHERIE-LA-QUEUE-DE-BOEUF-897804951.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/CONCEPT-HABITAT-825189525.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/D-R-H-484393632.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/DIJON-3D-823618632.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/DOYOUNO-SAS-831125620.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/DS-CAR-840753479.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/EFL-GERY-847766227.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ETABLISSEMENTS-PATOUILLET-435820048.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ETUDES-&-CONCEPTS-ECLAIRAGE-DISTRI-480509736.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/FCR-453373763.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/FINANCIERE-HELP-820221190.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/FL-POWER-804071173.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/GILPAYSAGES-828628735.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/GRZ-CONSULTING-850730169.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/IJK-847542032.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/JTG-SERVICES-848915062.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/KETOUFA-502211816.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/KIWI-CUBE-540011913.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/L'ATELIER-D'ANNE-MARIE-848605606.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/L'EMPREINTE-831166723.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LES-DEUX-TILLEULS-881440358.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MAISON-VERTE-58-829113844.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MEGNAUD-FRERES-378867089.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MENUISERIE-ET-AMENAGEMENT-CONCERTE-829772714.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MG-CONSTRUCTION-BOURGOGNE-838647832.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MH-CLEAN-VENISSIEUX-889028015.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MINOTERIE-MEGNAUD-511914236.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MURET-&-DESCHAMPS-843981788.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MY-AUTOMEDON-811217868.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/NAULIN-FINANCES-435382288.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/NIVERNAISE-DES-FARINES---MOULIN-DES-C-840717375.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ON.LY-848546875.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/PHILIPPE-GOURDON-410931208.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SARL-LE-BOREAL-828332429.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SARL-SILA-802237776.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SARL-TRANSPORTS-GRONDIN-848874970.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SERENITY-831000476.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/STEPHANE-LEVOIN-BRUNET-810194126.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/TC-RYORI-842166274.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/TD-PEINTURE-INDUSTRIELLE-ELECTROSTATIQUE-811520618.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/TOPH-EXPRESS-532578283.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/VAGAIS-841675481.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/VAN-DE-WEGE-503170292.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/VAOVERT-833729783.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/VAPO-CHIC.COM-799271853.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/VELO-LIBERTY-853476372.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/VERT-PUISAYE-823627476.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/VICTOR-GAYET-821616687.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/VILUX-839270436.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ACTI-LIVRES-483597902.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ALCHIMIE-BOURGOGNE-512534678.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ALLIANCE-DES-FORESTIERS-833419666.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ATELIER-THAIS-810300210.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AU-BON-POINT-894196112.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BFE-828434027.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BROYER-MACONNERIE-850641473.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/CASA-D'ISABEL-881645170.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/COMMUNICATION-ACTIVE-SARL-348142225.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/D.T.C.-INTERNATIONAL-831455894.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/DIMOBAT-505003418.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/DISTRIPIZ89-899740542.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/DOMAINE-DES-CHAUCHOUX-344692041.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ENTREPRISE-RENARD---B-838063279.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ETABLISSEMENTS-SARIC-ET-P.-FILS-820008282.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/EURL-BOI-815158308.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/FC-CONCEPT-SASU-827788621.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/FOYER-DES-JEUNES-TRAVAILLEURS-DU-CREUSOT-397677873.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/G.S.D-PARAY-887980415.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/GARCIA-489314963.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/GUILLOT---ECHALLIER-TOPOGRAPHIE-493219679.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/HAPPY-HOUSE-881441778.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/HURRICANE-US-GARAGE-495381790.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/K-TIA-901189001.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/KAYABEY-BOIS-809663396.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/L'ECOLE-BUISSONNIERE-848710323.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LA-GAZELLE-900306580.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LA-GRANGE-CHALON-897455937.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LES-DELICES-DE-FLORALYSA-797644440.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LIBERTISSIMMO-532637634.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LOST-WORLD-839395449.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MARIEJP-879514370.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MAX-D-832825434.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/NEGOCIANT-DE-LA-BRUYERE-751176504.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/NIDAL-903145787.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/PALMEIRA-509294930.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/PRALOC-&-ASSOCIES-852866367.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/RACH'L-834721524.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/RENOTECH-HABITAT-818251472.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SAJE-COIFFURE-830531950.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SARL-BARREAU-891358269.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SARL-EURO-ALU-EQUIPEMENT-430418343.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SARL-HENRY-BATIMENT-825171077.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SARL-PARC-DE-LOISIRS-DU-CHABLISIEN-491815718.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SBM-812258747.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SP2B-833510100.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/STEELYRAV-812614204.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SVPAC-SYNERGIES-VALO-PROMO-AUTO-COLLEC-452869472.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/TABARD-843270364.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/TRADI-FACAD-448296277.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/TVLL-844169078.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/URBAN-BENTO-897503306.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ABW-831379698.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AGIMENUISERIE-821342649.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ARBEO-438067381.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ART-METAL-842627242.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ASSISTANCE-ET-SERVICES-DE-CONCEPTION-839926110.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AUTO-SOINS-881948699.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BATIMENT-ET-RENOVATION-ROLLET-PATRICK-452342629.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BDC-889418240.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BELFRANCE-752451732.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BG-FORESTIER-71-851037424.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BK-FIBRES-842228504.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BVM-PROMOTION-491816179.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/CHEZ-FRANCOISE-ET-SEBASTIEN-477987978.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/CHOCOLAT-494725302.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/CMB-DIETETIQUE-831389432.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/D.S.I.P-824074314.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/DIJON-PIECES-MENAGER-451667398.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ENTREPRISE-AUGUSTE-ROSSI-309046787.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/EQUIPEER-828989962.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/FORESTLAG-811882703.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/HOME-DESIGN-850100348.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/J.L.H.-RESTAURATION-819162108.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/JOSEPHINE-DECO-841433378.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LA-VIE-BUISSONNIERE-SCIC-SARL-888221363.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LE-LYLOU-882574940.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MEDIAGROUP-499701589.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ORIGAMI-PACK-ET-PLV-523048593.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ROY-SERVICES-832204275.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/S.M.C.-SASU-809190333.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SARL-PAUL-PERCHE-401125646.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SAS.LE-RESTO-889618534.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SOCIETE-DE-MENUISERIE-BOIS-PELLETIER-401943063.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SOCIETE-T-ET-B-FONCIERE-451558894.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/T.R.E.E.-ENERGIE-820555738.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/TETRANE-530448232.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/TRAVAUX-RESEAUX-ENVIRONNEMENT-ELAGAGE-522414754.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/WILLYTIC-813995966.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/A.B.C-834429169.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ABS-STAR-822854428.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AE.BTP-800427320.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AGM-PEINTURE-502841687.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ALLIANCE-CONCEPT-893068098.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ARI-880929070.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/B.C.I.F.-441504313.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/B.C.I.F.-ADMINISTRATIONS---COLLECTIVITES-442335212.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BORN-TO-QUILT-528625353.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BOULANGERIE-PATISSERIE-ADAM-825086820.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BTD-SYSTEMS-498099290.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/CONCEPT-BOIS-DESIGN-852730969.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/EPICERIE-DE-GILIUS-839650025.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/EXPLOITATION-FORESTIERE-DE-LA-BRUYERE-490953817.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/GLT-LINE-893645622.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/GSA-DISTRIBUTION-813445624.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/HARAS-DE-LA-MERLUCHERIE-534368139.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/HORIZON-ZEN-851104661.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/IMEJI-443472428.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/IMMO-2A-381957638.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ISIMY-851837484.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/L2M-RENOVATION-808619381.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LA-PENICHE-D'AUXERRE-819915034.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LE-BOEUF-QUI-CHANTE-830078366.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LEC-PLOMBERIE-CHAUFFAGE-831215389.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LES-TOILES-HEBERGEMENT-EPHEMERE-881596407.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MAZENQ-JEAN-YVES-852619592.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/METAL-CONSTRUCTION-842656670.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MISS-WAFFLE-830167607.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MM-PRO-BATIMENT-853618957.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/MULTI-VARIABLE-FORMATION-884983123.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/NOES-848078713.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/NPM-MARKET-834711657.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/PHARMACIE-FOCH-794467407.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/PYXAL-448845941.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/RECYCLAGE-PIECES-POTS-METAUX-504880519.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/RO2-AVENTURE-528654924.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/S.T.A-821027612.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SARL-BODY-LIFT-881244479.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SARL-LES-BOULANGERIES-DE-GERMIGNY-414049619.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SARL-PLANCON-FRERES-423906932.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SASU-SEDRAT-ETANCHEITE-819590357.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SIRAC-DIJON-812194926.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/SOCIETE-NOUVELLE-GENNETIER-TECHNIQUES-419974084.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/STYLE-ET-CONCEPT-888337946.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/T.E.V.L-824467682.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/TS-AGRICOLES-823752886.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/UTILIMOTORS-811238039.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/VIDE'HOME-823806849.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/Y.B.K-789860780.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ACTA-PUBLICA-844517102.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AG-INDUSTRIES-SAS-819108143.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ALINE-THAI-SPA-850667841.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AM-MENUISERIE-845346279.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ASM-FERMETURES-820375814.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/AV-OCCAS-21-839243466.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BEKER-821260791.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/BHC-505056879.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/C.M.L.-LEVAGE-500697750.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/CGE-AUTOMOBILES-799044102.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/CHAMPS-PLAISANTS-830955407.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/DELAHAYE-423628676.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/DELOMAS-482852738.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/EN-ROUE-LIBRE-829209774.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ENTREMONT-HOTELLERIE-434881827.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/EURL-LA-BOUTIQUE-793792904.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/EURL-MARECHAL-389271446.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/FIABILEX-814973889.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/FRANCE-PRO-RHF-829126523.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/ICAU-FRANCE-343081741.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LA-BASE-879394799.html",
"https://www.societe.com/societe/LA-BELLE-MAISON-802577007.html",
]
```

I think the problem comes from cookies but I couldn't find anything on this subject and I'm a little stuck. Do you have a solution to successfully launch a loop with a large number of urls without being blocked?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apply "Cookie" in the headers dictionary like this.

```
headers = {
    "User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36",
    "cookie":"AHWqTUlhftkLIuXSbIVa5uKh77iLa_kw1Tx9rkm3xTMos06ERQq3MgXWSdg7-iCp9WA"
}
```

You can get a cookie from the DevTools of the browser. Go to the website, switch to the Application tab. Expand the Cookie section and then copy the cookie value.

[image]

I will also suggest you to add sleep intervals in between your code too. To use this, you will have to add `import time` at the top of the script.

```
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I need some clarification.
I am offered several cookies, can I use any? And for the time.sleep where should I place it exactly? in the loop or before?

Comment: @mat47 You have to identify which cookies to use by inspecting which ones are being used in session. I only saw one there so I included one. But you can include multiple as well. As for `time.sleep()` you can either place it at the end of the loop or the first line in the loop.